# How can I do INSERT to a dependency relation between 3 classes?

Tags: sql, insert, sql-insert, sqldependency, oracle-coherence

I have the mother class Boat and the two subclasses, sailing and motor. If it is a sail type, I have to know how many sails it has, if it is a motor, the power and if it is both a sail and a motor, all of them. The boat has the registration plate as PRIMARY KEY, so this is the FOREIGN KEY of the two subclasses. What I don't understand is how I can do the INSERTs for, depending on whether it's sail, motor or sail and motor, fill in the required information for each type.

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
INSERT INTO boat (registration, name)
VALUES('XXXXXXX','A');
INSERT INTO motor(registration, power)
VALUES ('XXXXXXX',35);
INSERT INTO sailing (registration, quantity)
VALUES ('XXXXXXX',3);
```

From what I understand, this would create a boat that is a sail and motor type. If I wanted to sail only, I would remove the motor INSERT and vice versa if I wanted it to be motor only.
I'm just getting started and I don't know if this is what I need to do.
Sorry if I didn't explain myself well. In theory the dependency relationship is optional and OR.

Comment: If this is the only difference between motor / sailing  / both boats I would create 2 nullable columns in the Boat table. Otherwise your solution looks reasonable.

Comment: Well, Boat has more attributes but I wanted to point that the important one is the registration plate, the PRIMARY KEY. What I wanted to know is if I want to INSERT information about a Sailing, Motor or both I have to first INSERT, with an specific registration plate lets say '111111', as if it were a Boat, and then make INSERTs depending on what i want with that registracion plate.

Comment: Yes, you must first insert into parent table Boat. And now you can reference the parent row  from  Motor, Sailing tables.